# Assert a function is not executed in Python unittest

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

I am using Django for my web development framework. And now I am writing unittest. How can  I assert that a function is not executed in my test code?

For example, this is the use case: *My test code is testing a user is typing a wrong password while signing in.* I want to make sure that reset password function is not executed in this use case.

Well, this doesn't really reflect the real situation but I hope you get my point.

Comment: how about adding a global counter to the function (e.g. for each execution of the function it is incremented by 1). test its value before and after the test - if it differs, it was called; if its the same it wasnt [workaround type of thing I guess....)

Comment: Mock `reset` function so it does nothing.

Answer (score 7):

What I would do is to use mock. Mock the function and assert that `mock_function.call_count==0`.

You can read more about mock here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to answer my own question. So far my solution is using [`Mock.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.called). Example this is where reset password function located: `utils/password.py`

```
class Password(object):

    def reset(self):
        ...
```

So I need to mock this object at my test code `test/login.py`

```
@patch('utils.password.Password.reset')
def test_wrong_password(self, mocked_password_reset):
    ...
    assert mocked_password_reset.called == False
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mock.patch.object` and `assert_not_called` or `call_count` to do this.
assume you function define in `mymodule.py`:

```
def function_can_not_be_called():
    pass

def func(call):
    if call:
        function_can_not_be_called()
```

test code in `test_mymodule.py`

```
import mymodule
import unittest
from mock import patch

class CTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(mymodule, "function_can_not_be_called")
    def test_MockFunc(self, mock_func):
        mymodule.func(0)
        mock_func.assert_not_called()

        mymodule.func(1)
        mock_func.assert_called_once()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```